# Change Bot Presence in Teams to Away

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Is there a way to change the bot presence in MS teams? It always appears Available.

Our chatbot is already published on the teams channel. In cases we wanted to deploy changes for our chatbot, we wanted to let the users know that they can't use the bot during that time. I was wondering if there are configurations needed in the Azure portal to handle the bot's presence.

If not, can the presence be handled through some bot framework middleware?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to change the presence of a Bot to away. Bot's presence is always available.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gousia-MSFT pointed out, you can't change the Bot's presence. The downtime on deploying a new feature isn't much, but if you are concerned about this, I would recommend deploying to a Deployment Slot. The slot is essentially up and running already, so when you swap your changes into the main slot, there should be no downtime. More informaiton on using deployment slots can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots). You will need to have a Standard or higher tier of service on your App Service Plan to use slots.